# cannot insert value to sqlite DB iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Well following this tutorial I have some problems in inserting values to my DB although everything seems to be working fine.

This is my code for inserting entries.

```
-(void)insertOrder:(MyOrderList*)entry
{
    // Create insert statement for the person
    NSString *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LIST (URL, CODE, EMAIL, FULL) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")", entry.db_url, entry.db_code, entry.db_email,entry.db_full];
    NSLog(@"SQL INSERTION COMMAND:%@",insertStatement);

    char *error;
    if ( sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
            NSLog(@"Order inserted.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
    }
}
```

And I can see "Order Inserted" being printed out.

This is my code for retrieving the list.

```
-(NSArray*) getList
{
    NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *queryStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT URL,CODE ,MAIL, FULL FROM LIST"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSLog(@"Query:%@",queryStatement);
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [queryStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Iterate over all returned rows
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"Url of my List is:%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);

            MyOrderList *person = [[MyOrderList alloc]initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] andCode:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] andEmail:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] andFull:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]];
      [persons addObject:person];

            // Release the person because the array takes ownership
            //[person release];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    //return [persons autorelease];
    return persons;

}
```

and this is how I use it in my .m file

```
  DataController *dataController = [[DataController alloc]init];
                [dataController initDatabase];
                //[dataController release];

                 MyOrderList *order  = [[MyOrderList alloc] initWithUrl:url_2 andCode:keycode andEmail:mail andFull:full_2 ];
                [dataController insertOrder:order];
                //data has been added
                NSMutableArray* persons = [dataController getList];
```

and I see that persons are 0.

From terminal I see this:

```
Admins-MacBook-Air:~ admin$ sqlite3 Users/admin/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/1A70F53B-133E-46AE-833E-13F205EA96EA/Documents/sqlite.db
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .schema
Error: unable to open database "Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/1A70F53B-133E-46AE-833E-13F205EA96EA/Documents/sqlite.db": unable to open database file
Admins-MacBook-Air:~ admin$
```

it's like my db is not even created.

this is my code for creating the DB.

```
-(void)initDatabase
{
    // Create a string containing the full path to the sqlite.db inside the documents folder
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"];
    NSLog(@"Path is:%@",databasePath);

    // Check to see if the database file already exists
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // Open the database and store the handle as a data member
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Create the database if it doesn't yet exists in the file system
        if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
        {
            // Create the PERSON table
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIST (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, URL TEXT, CODE TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, FULL TEXT)";
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the database with `sqlite3` from the Mac command line and examine it.  (The sqlite3 utility command syntax is on the SQLite web site.)

Comment: You're "undefined instance" errors are probably due to not having getList in DataController.h.

Comment: I added them, and now I got no warning. But still db is empty. I checked in the terminal also so check my edit..

Comment: Well, do some debugging.  As I suggested, find your database in Finder (I forget exactly where the emulator hides its files for each installed app, but you can probably find it with Google or by simply poking around a bit) then open a command window, cd to the directory where your DB is, and type `sqlite3 myDbName`.  Then go to the SQLite site to find the commands you can issue, or simply type `.help` (be sure to use the `.` before commands).

Comment: I did that as I said and you can see the results in my edited answer. It cannot find my DB, its like that it is not created.

Comment: But as to why you don't see any `persons`, maybe it's because you never insert the created `person` into your `persons` array.

Comment: You left the leading "/" off of "Users".  (This is why I suggested doing the `cd` -- then you know you have a valid directory, and you can `ls` its contents.)

Comment: Thanks! I put the / and found the DB. With testing sql statements it was a typo mistake. The column name was EMAIL instead of MAIL.

Comment: Note that putting the `sqlite3_column...` calls all on one line like that pushes them off the page and makes it harder to notice things like a misspelled field name.  Better to assign each result to a separate NSString (or whatever type) and then use those in your `init`.  There's really no efficiency difference between the two techniques, but readability is greatly improved if you break things up a bit.

Comment: Can I suggest you separate SQLite 'c' calls from the higher level Objective-C code. See the GitHub sample EasySQLite for code to do this:https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/EasySQLite